# Label does not change even model changed the value in mvvm

Tags: c#, mvvm

Can someone please tell me what is the mistake I have done ? Label in the view does not change even the Error.ErroMsg changed.

**xaml view**

```
<Label
  x:Name="ErrorMsg"
  Content="{Binding Path=Error.ErrorMsg, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
  Grid.Column="0"
  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
  Width="200"
  Height="26"/>
```

**View Model**

```
private ErrorModel error = new ErrorModel();

public ErrorModel Error
{
    get { return error; }
    set { error = value; }
}

// This method will be called by a state machine using a delegate
public void displayErrorMessage(string message)
{
    Error.ErrorMsg = message;
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    logger.Trace(" Successfully displayed the error message");
}
```

**Model**

```
// ModelBase inherited by INotifyPropertyChanged and IDisposable
class ErrorModel : ModelBase
{
    private string errorMsg;
    public string ErrorMsg
    {
        get { return errorMsg; }
        set { errorMsg = value; OnPropertyChanged("ErrorMsg"); }
    }
    public ErrorModel() {
        errorMsg = "TestHello";
    }
}
```

**ModelBase**
 public class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
    {
        /// 
        /// Default constructor of view model base
        /// 
        protected ModelBase()
        {
        }

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialized property changed event handler
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// This function will call by public setters of the model class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Specific property name that needs to identify unique model member</param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // Initialize handler by using property changed event handler delegate
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        // Check that current handler is available or not
        if (handler != null)
        {
            // Initialize property changed event args
            var propertyChangedEventArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            // Call back using property changed event handler
            handler(this, propertyChangedEventArgs);
        }     
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is calle when leaving the view model
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.OnDispose();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Model dependent data is cleared here
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void OnDispose() { }
}
```

//Calling displayErrorMessage through a delegate

string cpDoesntWorkError = "Charging point not available." 
 this.uiDelegator.showErrorMessage(cpDoesntWorkError);

**GUIDelegator**

```
 public delegate void DisplayErrorMessageDelegate(string message);    

 /// <summary>
        /// This will register the ErrorMesssage delegate passed by the RCU_GUI
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="del">ErrorMessageDelegate object which need to registered will be passed</param>

        public void setDisplayErrorMessageDelegate(DisplayErrorMessageDelegate del)
        {
            displayErrorMessageDelegate = del;
            logger.Trace("Error message delegate successfully set by RCU_GUI");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Call back to the displayErrorMessage which is in RCU_GUI
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">Error message need to be displayed</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void showErrorMessage(string message)
        {
            // If the error message delegate is not null
            if (displayErrorMessageDelegate != null)
            {
                logger.Trace("Displaying the error message");
                displayErrorMessageDelegate(message);
            }
            else
                logger.Trace("null display error message delegate");
        }
```

Comment: It looks like that, the problem lies somewhere in `uiDelegator` and how it is invoking `displayErrorMessage` (whether they are using the same View Model instance), because rest of the code looks fine.

Comment: I have added the code of the delegate class. Please help me to find out the problem here. I cannot find out why it is not updating the view even though the model changes its attribute  ErrorMsg.

Comment: Could you show entire code for View Model as well as place where you are calling `setDisplayErrorMessageDelegate` method?

Comment: I am calling it in the constructor of the viewModel. I know that writing a specific relay command for changing the content of the the label can be done without any problem Here also I have bind a button with a relayCommand which basically goes inside the state machine and through  the state machine I will be passing the error to the viewModel through a delegate . But when I change the ErrorMsg content in the viewmModel, the view will not get updated. Is there any method to update the view ?

Comment: At the beginning in `Label` in your view do you have string `TestHello` displayed? Did you tried to change directly in View Model `ErrorMsg` property to see whether view is updated?

Comment: Omg found the mistake. The same view has been loaded twice from two ways and code really worked on the 1st object that has been created. Then the second object replaces everything. :( My bad. Thank you very much for the support given and extremely sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be aware of few things:

1. Whether your method `OnPropertyChanged` in `ModelBase` properly raises `PropertyChanged` event
2. In your **View Model** in property `Error` you are not notifying view that this property changes. Then some other code might assign new `ErrorModel` instance before `displayErrorMessage` method is called. Due to that view is not aware that `Error` property changed, so it still display `TestHello` string. If that's the case you can modify your **View Model**:

   ```
   public ErrorModel Error
   {
       get { return error; }
       set { error = value; OnPropertyChanged("Error"); }
   }
   ```
3. Your delegate which is calling `displayErrorMessage` method must use the same **View Model** object instance which is assigned to `DataContext` property of View. Because if not, then definitely View doesn't get notified about property changes.

Comment: Yes onPropertyChnaged method triggered and it triggered the PropertyChangedEventHandler. The string value also successfully assigned to the Error.ErrorMsg when I debugged the program. How can I notify the view that my property has changed ? I thought that it happens automatically. Please help me

Comment: Add `OnPropertyChanged("Error")` method call to setter of the `Error` property.

Comment: Could you include in your question `ModelBase` class and also how you are actually calling `displayErrorMessage` method?

Comment: It does even work without a OnPropertyChanged("Error").
And I just tested it wiith the given Codepieces.

Comment: Well I must mention that I have called the displayErrorMessage from a delegate inside the statemachine. But anyhow the Error.ErrorMsg is updating with the value I am passing through the delegate. Sure I will upload the code as well

Comment: Are you sure that delegate is using the same **ViewModel** which is assigned to the `DataContext` of **View**?

Comment: Yes the delegate is using the same viewModel that the view is assigned for. It goes through "displayErrorMessage" method once the delegate is executed  and ErrorMsg is successfully assigned with the value that I pass. I have added the source codes also. I still could not find the problem here.